# How to pass on parameters from pretty URL to JSP pages?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, friendly-url

I trying to do two things at once and I don't seem to find answers that can do both.

I'm trying this:

**I want URLs ending in `/user/{parameter}` to be mapped to a JSP page user.jsp where I can access the parameter.**

I find ways to pass parameters from the web.xml file to the JSP using this method

```
<init-param>
<param-name>someParam</param-name>
<param-value>itsValue</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And I find ways to create URL filters and map them to Java Servlets.

What I need is a combination. Also, what I found on passing URL parameters to Servlets wasn't too detailed either, so a good reference on that would also be more than welcome!

Answer (score 4):

> *I want URLs ending in /user/{parameter} to be mapped to a JSP page user.jsp where I can access the parameter.*

Map a servlet on `/user/*` and use `HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()` to extract the path info.

E.g.

```
@WebServlet("/user/*")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo(); // "/{parameter}"
        // ...
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/user.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

That's basically all. Use the usual `String` methods like `substring()` and/or `split()` to break down the path info in usable parts.

Answer (score 1):

Use a base-url servlet to parse the URL and perform a conditional servlet forwarding to the appropriate JSP.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher().forward(JSPurl)
```

Let us say you have a URL branch `/sales/`. Under this URL branch, you would allow the following URLs to to be serviced by `/implemented/usersales.jsp` :

- /sales/liquour/users/{region}
- /sales/liquour/soft/users/{region}
- /sales/toiletries/users/{type}

and the following URLs to be serviced by `/implemented/products.jsp`
- /sales/groceries/products/{section}
- /sales/groceries/meat/products/{region}
- /sales/groceries/vegetables/beans/products/{region}

You would have a web.xml servlet mapping for servlet class org.myorg.SalesHandler to be mapped to /sales/.

In the service method override in org.myorg.SalesHandler servlet class,
analyse the URL pattern (using regexp or otherwise) and then conditionally forward the request using

```
request.getRequestDispatcher().forward(JSPurl)
```

#### JAX-RS

But why would you do that when we have jax-rs?

[How to forward from a JAX-RS service to JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984338/how-to-forward-from-a-jax-ws-service-to-jsp).

JAX-RS may seem daunting at first, but it is actually very simple and intuitive to implement.